# Jenkins - How to pass values from pom.xml to downstream job (free style)

Tags: maven, jenkins

I've set up 2 free style jobs, build-app and deploy-app. build-app poll the scm and builds the app, which is Maven based, and install the artifact in a web server (internal repository server), then it calls deploy-app. I would like to pass the version of the pom file () to the downstream job so it can download the correct artifact and install it on the machine. I found some answers suggesting put the version string in a properties file and use InjectEnv plugin, but I prefer read it from the pom itself. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build inside Maven, you have access to the pom file version as `${program.version}` and can do anything you wish with it.

The downstream freestyle job can also run Maven using the same pom but a different target. The version should be the same if you take care to keep it from changing in the interim. (This suggests a procedure that should always be followed.)

So, for example, that Maven target can run a Groovy script or an Ant script that will pick up the correct file from the repo and deploy it.

Comment: Is there a built-in target that just read the pom file? Then I can use Invoke Shell Script to wget the artifact. Or, how do I add custom target that downloads the artifact?

Comment: The steps to download/deploy/copy/etc will need to be running inside Maven. You will want to pick a lifecycle phase that suits you and happens after `deploy`.